# Website crashing (in) Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, web, crash, sifr

I have created a newly designed site that went live just last week. I have had reports back from a friend of a friend that it crashes in Firefox. They haven't passed on what version they are using, but hinted that it was on the mac.

I haven't been able to recreate this crash at all, and wondered if anybody out there either experienced the same, or had any idea why this might be the case.

FYI the site uses a mix of jQuery plugins and SIFR throughout.

The website in question is http://www.visualworks.co.uk

Thanks in advance
Craig

Comment: I tried it in Firefox on a PC though, but Firefox 3.6, and I couldn't get it to crash. It would be alot easier though to help if you described the kind of crash as well, if it was some javascript who timed out or if the site didn't load at all. Try and get some more information from your friends. I can try it on a MAC later this afternoon as well when I get home. I'll get back to you then.

Comment: A little information on what you mean by 'crashing' might be useful.

Comment: sorry i use Firefox 3.6.10 and it doesn't crash for me - so you can exclude that version from your investigation

Comment: Works for me in 3.6.10, Windows 7

Comment: Hi, Sorry if 'crashing' sounds a bit vague. I haven't been able to get that information myself, as I mentioned its a freind of a friend that reported it, and since I've not seen any errors like that, I haven't been able to ascertain exactly what is meant. Yet anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me... Firefox 3.6 on Windows. I do have Flash installed.

You could fire off the website through Browser Shots and see if it detects any problems on the specific browser and operating system.

http://browsershots.org/

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 3.6.10 running on Mac OS X 10.6.4 works fine for me, just so you know.